# Remove duplicate row in array based on specific column values in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array like this:

```
array = [[0.91 0.33 0.09]
         [0.52 0.63 0.05]
         [0.91 0.33 0.11]
         [0.52 0.63 0.07]
         [0.62 0.41 0.01]
         [0.36 0.37 0.01]]
```

I need it to remove the row with the larger value in the third column if the first two column values are duplicate. So this:

```
array2 = [0.91 0.33 0.11]
         [0.52 0.63 0.07]
         [0.62 0.41 0.01]
         [0.36 0.37 0.01]]
```

I want a pythonic way to do this without for loops if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Quick two common ways:

1. Python stdlib module `itertools` has a function `filter()`
2. Use a List comprehension

Since you have the condition, "if the first two column values are duplicate", you'll have to do some grouping first, and `itertools` also has `groupby()`.